# Can I get the request parameters from a fetch promise?

Tags: javascript, fetch

**tl;dr**

After I execute a `fetch` call, can I access the original request data (*e.g. headers, method, url, etc.*)?

---

I'm using `fetch()` to build an API client.

I have some helpers that modify the request (*e.g. `getJson()` adds `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` to the request header*).

I want to write a unit test that verifies that that `getJson` does, in fact, add the `Content-Type` header.

In order to do this, I want to read the **actual request information that went out**.

Is it possible to access this information? If so, how?

> It's worth noting that I tried building a `Request` object and pass *it* to my helpers so I can return it for the tests. Safari, however, doesn't seem to support native `Request` objects yet. I need to support Safari. Also, it's still experimental... so, I'm probably going to scrap this approach altogether.

Comment: Just a side question, out of curiosity: if you run a unit test, why do you specifically aim at Safari? Do you run unit tests in Safari?

Comment: Speaking of `fetch`, it resolves into an instance of Response object and it doesn’t contain the data about request. It has “headers” property but it refers to response headers. So if the test doesn’t have access to the context where request is being made, you can check the response headers. They are not guaranteed by the API to contain the data you need but implicitly Content-Type in the response should be one that is expected, which implies that it was requests. But I’m actually no less curious to see if anyone comes up with a solution.

Comment: @ri-chan That's a fair point. No, I'm not running unit tests in Safari. I just figured that if I'm going to introduce the option of returning the request, somebody may want to use it outside of testing. (I just happen to be using Safari right now because it allows me to easily disable CORS; handy for testing).

Comment: No, from your frontend JavaScript code running in a browser, you can’t access the request headers that the browser sends. There’s no API exposed to frontend JavaScript code that would enable you do do that. And anyway, the browser itself adds additional headers to the request after your code has already executed. So if you want to write a unit test that checks the request headers, you’d need to do that not from your frontend code but instead from the network/server side; for example, by running some code on the server the request is sent to, to check the headers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question but I'll try my best.

The JS fetch() should return a response which includes all of the data that was sent.

The following code should return the headers send by your fetch.

`fetch(yourURL, yourOptions).then((response) => response.headers)`

Comment: I want the entire request data, not just the response headers. For example, I want to see whether the request was a `get` or a `post`.

Comment: In that case you should just return just `response` (not `response.headers`). Something like the get or post types are set before the fetch() so you should just able to assign them to a var and read them.